# BSOD UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION error

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm getting random BSOD crashes with the crash code: `UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION` (the PC can run for a long time, then it crashes with the BSOD out of nowhere), and the guys over the subreddit /r/TechSupport told me that I should use the Display Driver Uninstaller in safe mode to fix this. I followed the guide on their website (the subreddit has its own website for guides), but it didn't work (I had 3 crashes before uninstalling display drivers, and 2 after that). Here's my [DxDiag report](https://pastebin.com/a0RRKCKn) if you want to view my hardware.

It just so happens that the crash only occurs after I updated my NVIDIA GameReady driver (and while Android Studio is still running, but I'm not sure if that's the main cause), and I was unable to roll back this driver to the previous version, the option was grayed out in Device Manager. The guide on rtech.support also has information on how to troubleshoot BSOD, and since my minidump folder is empty ([related guide](https://rtech.support/docs/factoids/bsod.html)), I exported Windows Event Viewer items under /Windows/System to CSV ([here it is](https://gist.github.com/minhngoc25a/cebd806bb9a31218a34ccfc13fd81552)). I also have a minidump file that's not in the Minidump folder, but in the directory containing the Minidump folder, and the file is over 2GB ([anonfile link](https://anonfiles.com/Ues0h2Z3y1/MEMORY_DMP)).

That's all I have. Thank you for your help!